# Any site out there that let's me run test SQL queries on sample databases?

Tags: mysql, t-sql, web

You wanna test a GROUP BY on some sample data in the browser without having to install a DB engine and you don't have a remote access to any cloud database?

Yeah, me too. Let's say it is for educational purposes. MSSQL or MySQL flavoured SQL would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

[sqlcourse](http://www.sqlcourse.com/)

Answer (score 1):

1. [W3Schools SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_tryit.asp)
2. [SQLCourse](http://sqlcourse.com/select.html)
3. [SQLCourse 2](http://sqlcourse2.com/select2.html)

I recommend W3Schools.

Comment: i don't think one should use w3schools. it's pooly written and full of errors (for more information, take a look at http://w3fools.com/)